# i am building app from Udemy . when I press drawing button it stuck and throw function error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am building filter page in drawing when I press on filter page it throw error message. it is because of function which I have used .

////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////

[image]

////////////////////////////////////
[image]

/////////////////////////////////

[image]
////////////////

//////////////////////////////

```
import 'package:f2/widgets/main_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/filters';

  @override
  State<FilterScreen> createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {
  bool _glutenFree = false;
  bool _vegetarian = false;
  bool _vegan = false;
  bool _lactoseFree = false;

  Widget _buildSwitchListTitle(
      String title, String description, bool currentValue, Function function) {
    return SwitchListTile(
      title: Text(title),
      value: currentValue,
      subtitle: Text(description),
      onChanged: function(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(" filter page"),
      ),
      drawer: MainDrawer(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Text(
              "Adjust your meal selection",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView(
            children: [
              _buildSwitchListTitle(
                "Gluten - free",
                "Only include Gluten-free meals",
                _glutenFree,
                (value) => setState(() {
                  _glutenFree = value;
                }),
              )
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't share screenshots or images of the code or errors. Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far

Comment: I have been asking similar questions for almost three years. nobody complained yet. Yesterday a person from Barzel solved my question which was the same question as that.I have added a screenshot. you can check it in my profile.

Comment: there is just a minor error, just a syntax error.  the function inside the _buildSwitchListTitle throw error.

Comment: bro I asked to chatgpt it solve my problem. chatgpt suggest me to change  Function function to void Function(bool) function and chatgpt also told me to change  onChanged: function(),  to  onChanged: function,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```dart
Widget _buildSwitchListTitle(
  String title, 
  String description,
  bool currentValue, 
  void Function(bool) function,
) {
  return SwitchListTile(
    title: Text(title),
    value: currentValue,
    subtitle: Text(description),
    onChanged: function,
  );
}
```